# Mention a specific potential adviser in the PhD statement of purpose who strongly suggest to apply and use his name in the SOP

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I am writing my statement of purpose for my Ph.D. and I want to work in a specific field with a specific professor in the department that I am going to apply for. I sent an email for that professor asking if he/she is accepting Ph.D. students and he/she strongly suggested me to apply and use his name in the SOP. If he already took the students he want. will I risk my admission to that school?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You _want to work in a specific field with a specific professor_ and the professor suggested you to use his name. Then you said "_will I risk my admission to that school?_".  What's the risk here?

Comment: If it turns out that the professor chose someone else and is no longer accepting students, would you still be interested in joining that department? If so, maybe you could explain that too in the SOP.